# Using AND with datediff

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I just can't find it anywhere I look. I am trying to use AND to affect the results of my query. Query below.

```sql
select first_name, log_in, date_opened, datediff(log_in, date_opened) as date_diff
from table1
where log_in < date_opened;
```

So that first query works fine.  It gives me only the rows where the log_in date is less than date_opened and then the total days difference between the two, which is great. However, I am looking to add an AND to the query to exclude certain totals. For example below:

```sql
select first_name, log_in, date_opened, datediff(log_in, date_opened) as date_diff
from table1
where log_in < date_opened and date_diff > 1;
```

Problem is the alias column date_diff is not recognized as a real column, so I get an error message.  I tried using HAVING instead of AND but that didn't work (not that I thought it would).  I basically want to exclude the rows that have zero.  Anyone has any idea on what I'd use instead of 'and date_diff > 1'?

Comment: `where log_in < date_opened and datediff(log_in, date_opened) > 1;` use the calc as the alias is not available there

Comment: Hm, i'm not familiar with calc but i think i'm ok now.  I just had to use the entire expression again and that made everything right.  Thanks though !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either repeat the expression in your where clause (that is, use `datediff(log_in, date_opened) > 1` instead of `date_diff > 1`), or use a derived table, and add the condition on the enclosing query.

Example of using derived table:

```sql
select first_name, log_in, date_opened, date_diff
from (
    select first_name, log_in, date_opened, datediff(log_in, date_opened) as date_diff
    from table1
    where log_in < date_opened
)
where date_diff > 1
```

Comment: I think i'm going crazy.  I thought sure i had did that but it was obviously just me :) Thanks a lot for the response  !!!